# Некорректная кодировка символов

Tags: c++, ascii

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << int('й') << endl;
    char a = 0;
    cin.get(a);
    cout << int(a) << endl;
}
```

При передаче в `cin.get();`,например,символа 'й' выдает разные результаты:

```
-23
-87
```

Почему так? И так 'багаются' все символы кириллицы. Догадываюсь,что там что-то с кодировками,но в рамках одной системы кодирование должно быть во всех местах одинаковым,нет разве? И,если не сложно,объясните,как пишутся программы под разные системы? Везде же разные кодировки,и программы,которые завязаны на этом,работая на системе разработчика,не будут работать на другой системе. Я совсем уж не силен в Web,ибо изучаю C++ и это мой первый язык,но если подумать,то там ситуация еще страшнее?Там же нужно передавать данные и.т.д. А как это делать,если кодировки разные?

Comment: ascii - это когда только латинский алфавит. А ситуация с кодировками, юникодом и их поддержкой в С++ - просто ужас.

Comment: В вебе как раз то все упростили до нельзя. Всю магию за вас делает enctype

Comment: @VTT Просто пытаюсь написать велосипед в виде программы,которая будет считать кол-во слов в тексте.И в алгоритме есть проверка,какой код у символа(явно преобразовывается и проверяется). И вот поэтому я задумался,вдруг на других системах с другими кодировками программа будет работать неправильно?

Comment: Я очень сильно подозреваю, что и на вашей оно работает неправильно, т.к. однобайтовые кодировки с кириллицей сейчас практически не используются. А utf8 является многобайтовом и одиного `char` не достаточно для хранения одной буквы.

Comment: @VTTда забил я уже на кириллицу..а вот если кодировка установленная будет не ASCII,а Unicode,например?Все же пойдет криво и будет работать неправильно,даже если будет использоваться латиница?

Comment: Unicode - это не кодировка, это набор символов. А коды символов ASCII из кодировки ASCII соответствуют кодам соотв. символов в кодировках UTF8 UTF16 UTF32

Comment: @VTT Такие соответствия только в UTF-ах или предусмотрено и в других кодировках?

Comment: В каких других? Есть конечно куча не юникод кодировок, там может быть по-разному, но и там во многих ASCII часть идет без изменений.

Comment: @VTT Понял,спасибо за разъяснение.